# How do C developers work with assembly that's foreign to them?

Tags: c, assembly

I was looking through [a `C` code snippet](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/30214) when i came across this line of assembly code:

```
char *buf = alloca(0x2000);
asm volatile("" :: "m" (buf));
```

I don't know what this means. In my investigation, i've learned that that there are many different types of assembly languages (e.g., MASM, NASM, GAS, etc.), and in my (very limited) experience, the author rarely specifies which one they're using.

What does this line mean; and more importantly, how do `C` developers (presumably not versed in assembly) research assembly code they come across in this manner?

Comment: This isn't "assembly code". It's an `asm` statement. In fact, it contains no code at all, as evidenced by the `""`.

Comment: Since it's part of a C source file, it's handled by the C compiler. Since you haven't told us which compiler you're using, I can only suggest that you consult your C compiler's documentation; search for "asm".

Comment: They look it up, probably. Assembly is not some arcane dark magic, as some people seem to think - you can just look up the individual parts and reason about what that means about the whole.

Comment: Typically the available assembly instructions are available in the Processor manuals published by the Processor manufacturer (eg Intel). (However as others have noted the "assembly" you've posted contains no instructions - it's just serving as a memory barrier, for reasons that aren't clear without more context).

Comment: @harold: Assembler is not some arcane dark magic, but I know several assemblers for several different processors, but `asm volatile("" :: "m" (buf));` doesn't tell me which assembler or which processor and it looks Greek to me. So it is something that not everyone can understand.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I wasn't aware there was a difference between assembly and `asm` statements. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The snippet is neither MASM, GAS, NASM, etc. It is [inline assembly](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#s5), and the syntax is documented in the C compiler's documentation.

The syntax is tricky even if you are already familiar with pure assembly because it has to specify how to connect the C part with the assembly part and vice-versa.

The statement `asm volatile("" :: "m" (buf));` would typically be an empty bit of assembly (not a noop but an actual absence of instructions), with such binding instructions `"m"` that make the statement amount to a [memory barrier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier) from the point of view of the C compiler.

EDIT: a comment by StackOverflow user Jester below a now-deleted answer says that the purpose of the statement is more likely to prevent `buf`, and thus the `alloca` call, to be optimized out by the compiler by pretending that the assembly code `""` reads from it.

I believe that the C11 standard offers cleaner ways to express memory barriers, but I haven't had the chance to investigate yet. Anyway, as a way to specify a memory barrier, the above can be a way to target “GCC and compilers that aim for GCC compatibility, even if slightly old” as a larger set of compilers than “C compilers correctly implementing all of the C11 standard”. Actually, the Wikipedia page on C11 cites `asm volatile ("" : : : "memory");` as an example in the discussion of memory barriers.